# C++ function template with function as argument which depends on additional parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have implementation of line-search algorithm, e.g. [this Brent method](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/master/cpp/common/optimization/lineSearch.h), and I would like to make generic template of it which would allow me optimize any scalar function with respect to one parameter `x` but I would like to plug in `error_func` which depend not only on `x` but also on some other parameters.

maybe (pseudo)-code would be more illustrative what I want to do:

**general library:**

```
typedef double( *scalar_function1D )(double);

// this function vary "x" in order to make error_func(x) close to zero
template< scalar_function1D error_func>
double lineSearch_Brent ( double x, double xmin, double xmax, double tol ){
   double f = error_func(x);
   while( abs( f )>tol ){
       f = error_func(x);
       // body of line search algorithm, details not important
   }
   return x;
}
```

**specific use case:**

```
// we would like to find optimal "x" for this model_error function for given "params"
double model_error( double x, int n, double * params ... /* many other parameters there */ ){
    // body of specific model for error function which depends on "x" but also on other parameters; details not importaint
}

double optimize_x_for_given_model( double xmin, double ymin, int n, double * params ){
   // how to plug in "params" now ?!?
   return lineSearch_Brent<model_error>( 0.5*(xmin+xmax), xmin, xmax, 1.0e-8 );
}
```

the **obvious problem** is that `model_error` is not of type `scalar_function1D` since it has more parameters.

I know that this kind of problem can be solved by *Object oriented programing* e.g. like this:

```
class Scalar_function1D{ public virtual double eval(double); } // shared interface

class Model_error : public Scalar_function1D { // specific implementation
     public:
     int n;
     double * params;
     virtual double eval(double){ 
        // body which depends on "params"
     };
}
```

But I would like to know how to do it using function templates.

Comment: Where do the other parameters in the error function come from?

Comment: the other parameters specify the problem to optimize. E.g. consider I have a function in N-dimensional space, which I want to optimize along a particular 1D line. So the `params` would 1) describe the shape of the function to optimize 2) specify the direction of the line. Parameter `x` would be coordinate along that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a non-type template parameter:

```
template< scalar_function1D error_func>
double lineSearch_Brent ( double x, double xmin, double xmax, double tol ) { ... }
```

just pass an arbitrary function object:

```
template <class ScalarFunction1D>
double lineSearch_Brent (ScalarFunction1D error_func, double x, 
    double xmin, double xmax, double tol ) { ... }
```

This allows you to just pass in, for instance, a lambda that captures some other params:

```
lineSearch_Brent([=](double x){ return model_error(x, n, params); },
     0.5*(xmin+xmax), xmin, xmax, 1.0e-8);
```

or whatever as appropriate.

Comment: the lambda function is resolved in compile time and can be inlined ?